# Firebase functions not deploying in chosen region (and memory allocation)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I am exporting my Firebase Functions so all functions should have the same region:

```
import * as firebaseFunctions from 'firebase-functions';
export const functions = firebaseFunctions.region(FIREBASE_REGIONS.europe);
export const scheduledDoSomething = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(doSomething);
```

However, when I export a function using the `functions` constant, the region is sometimes set to the US. The memory is also suddenly set to 2GB sometimes, even though the default is 256MB, making me have to explicitly set the `.runWith({ memory: '256MB' })` property on the function. This is only for some functions (not all), and I have to specify some redundant properties on the function when exporting it:

```
// The region is already set on the *functions* object
export const scheduledDoSomething = functions.runWith({ memory: '256MB' }).region('europe-west1').pubsub.schedule('every every 1 minutes').onRun(() => doSomething());
```

Comment: What value do you get when you log `FIREBASE_REGIONS.europe`?

Comment: `europe-west1` so that should be ok :/

Comment: It seemed to be an issue by using `functions` instead of `firebaseFunctions`. Do you know why it's like thata?